# Python dataframe: Standard deviation of last one year of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, standard-deviation

I have dataframe `df` with daily stock market for 10 years having columns `Date`, `Open`, `Close`.

I want to calculate the daily standard deviation of the `close` price. For this the mathematical formula is:

Step1: Calculate the daily interday change of the `Close`

Step2: Next, calculate the daily standard deviation of the daily interday change (calculated from Step1) for the last 1 year of data

Presently, I have figured out Step1 as per the code below. The column `Interday_Close_change` calculates the difference between each row and the value one day ago.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df['Close_float'] = df['Close'].astype(float)
df['Interday_Close_change'] = df['Close_float'].diff()
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

**Questions:**

(a). How to I obtain a column `Daily_SD` which finds the standard deviation of the last 252 days (which is 1 year of trading days)? On Excel, we have the formula `STDEV.S()` to do this.

(b). The `Daily_SD` should begin on the 252th row of the data since that is when the data will have 252 datapoints to calculate from. How do I realize this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to calculate a rolling standard deviation, with the rolling window consisting of previous 252 rows.

Pandas has many `.rolling()` [methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html#pandas.Series.rolling), including one for standard deviation:

```
df['Daily_SD'] = df['Interday_Close_change'].rolling(252).std().shift()
```

If there is less than 252 rows available from which to calculate the standard deviation, the result for the row will be a null value (`NaN`).  Think about whether you really want to apply the `.fillna('')` method to fill null values, as you are doing.  That will convert the entire column from a numeric (`float`) data type to `object` data type.

Without the `.shift()` method, the current row's value will be included in calculations.  The `.shift()` method will shift all rolling standard deviation values down by 1 row, so the current row's result will be the standard deviation of the previous 252 rows, as you want.

**with `pandas` version >= 1.2 you can use this instead:**

```
df['Daily_SD'] = df['Interday_Close_change'].rolling(252, closed='left').std()
```

The `closed=left` parameter will exclude the last point in the window from calculations.